# Strange schema naming with EF core code-first

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm having a weird issue that I've never seen before, with schema naming using EF core code-first.

I just created a new class `LogEntry` used to log SMS and emails sent to our users.

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public LogEntry(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; set; } // Enum
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I then added configuration in my database context class, in `OnModelCreating(modelBuilder modelBuilder)`

```
public virtual DbSet<LogEntry> Log { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LogEntry>(entity => 
    {
        entity.HasKey(log => log.Id);
        
        entity.HasIndex(log => log.Date);
        entity.HasIndex(log => log.Provider);
        entity.HasIndex(log => log.Recipient);
        ...
    });
}
```

Then I ran `dotnet ef migrations add SomeMigration` to actually add the migration. I setup auto migration so it automatically updates my database when the project launches. So far so good.

Now, once I went to check out the new tables it created, I made a weird naming convention regarding the databae schema.

***My IIS website application pool is running with a specific managed AD user, let's call it `msvc-log-api`***

I'm used to EF always using the `dbo` schema, as it default to that schema, but for some weird reason, EF decided to create a new schema named after my managed AD user `mydomain\msvc-log-api$`. This means that my tables are named in the following way:

- `mydomain\msvc-log-api$.__EFMigrationHistory`
- `mydomain\msvc-log-api$.Log`

Any idea why this is happening, and do I really need to add `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo")` to mitigate this issue?

Comment: this happened to us also, we were forced to reset the migrations and use `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo")`, any luck finding the reason of this ?

Comment: Hello @ModarNa. I haven't yet found the reason for this issue. I've done the same as you, but it's jsut a workaround. It does work fine however.